# Sending an encrypted and digitally signed email from Outlook to other webmail clients

Tags: gmail, smime, exchange, microsoft-outlook

The company I work for uses Microsoft Exchange 2016 for email and we have S/MIME certificates for email encryption and digital signatures. Encryption and signing works for other exchange users, but is it possible to send encrypted email to other webmail clients like Gmail and Yahoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always possible to *send* the messages (provided that you have the recipient's certificate for encryption).

The question is whether the recipient can *read* them, and the answer is "it varies a lot".

- Public mail providers (Yahoo, etc.) almost never offer this.

  Gmail (the free version) can *verify signatures* via S/MIME, but cannot *decrypt* messages as there is no option to upload or generate a personal S/MIME keypair. (That's still more than most other public webmail sites, which don't support S/MIME at all.)
- Corporate mail service (hosted or at least a business plan) has a much greater *chance* of S/MIME support. But you still cannot know for sure until you actually test it.

  For example, G Suite Gmail (the business version) *does* support S/MIME decryption (and signing & encryption). Among on-premises software, at least IceWarp and Horde IMP (and of course Exchange) have S/MIME support.
- Finally, many mail providers support IMAP4 and/or POP3, allowing the same message to be opened in a desktop app which has S/MIME support.

  For example, if I receive an encrypted message to my Gmail inbox, I can't read it from within Gmail – but I can open Claws or Thunderbird and access the same mailbox via IMAP.

  For many corporate mail users, a desktop app (typically Outlook) *is* their primary means of using the company's mail service – even if it's not Exchange.

In the end, it should be fine to sign all your messages, but check with your recipient before using encryption.